# Invalid syntax error on running AWS command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am getting the below exception while trying to run any AWS command on my MacBook, for example:

**Command**

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket my_backup  --region us-west-2 --create- 
bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=us-west-1
```

**Exception**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/avinash/.local/share/virtualenvs/pipend_shell_3- 
x8skfE25/bin/aws", line 7, in <module>
from aws.main import main
File "/Users/avinash/.local/share/virtualenvs/pipend_shell_3- 
x8skfE25/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aws/main.py", line 23
print '%(name)s: %(endpoint)s' % {
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using Python 3.6.5 and have installed `aws`:

```
pip install aws
```

Comment: The underscore is not allowed in the bucket name. Also, just to be sure, you're entering in that command all on one line?

Comment: @DavidFairbanks Thanks for pointing it out but result is same even after i replace underscore with hyphen

Comment: What OS are your running the AWS CLI on? If Windows, which install method (MSI or pip)? The syntax error is coming from the SDK. The print statement is for Python 2 and you are running Python 3. If you are on Windows try again using the latest Python 2.7 (or install from the MSI which includes the correct version of Python). For Windows the MSI method is what I recommend to install the AWS CLI.

Answer (score 28):

I figured out the issue. I did `pip install aws` instead of `pip install awscli`.

We need to use the below command to install AWS CLI:

```
pip install awscli
```

Comment: this is actually the correct answer. The 'aws' command you're using is not the aws cli

Answer (score 0):

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket my_backup  --region us-west-2 --create-
bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=us-west-1
```

The regions for bucket creation and constraint are different. Both should be *us-west-2* or *us-west-1*.

The "my-bucket" name could also be a restricted name and you might have to choose another name.

Comment: Thanks! But, this was just one of the command, actually all the aws commands were failing with same exception. though you are right, there are other syntax errors in this command, but aws actually tells us the exact issue in that case, like bucket name is not valid.

Comment: But not two lines?